# Java REST POST method: HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

This is probably just a stupid mistake, but it's got me stuck for a pretty long time, and no other similar question here had an answer that worked for me.

I have a REST web service in Java (created in Eclipse, hosted in Tomcat), an it's supposed to accept a POST login in JSON.

```
import java.sql.Date;
import java.sql.Time;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET; 
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path; 
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;  

@Path("/UserService") 
public class UserService {  
   Dao dao = new Dao();  

   @GET 
   @Path("/users") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
   public List<User> getUsers(){
      return dao.getAllUsers();
   }  

   @POST
   @Consumes("application/json")
   @Path("/login") 
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
   public User login(final LoginBean params){
       return new User();

       /*User u = new User();
       u.setEmail(params.email);
       u.setPassword(params.password);
      return dao.login(u);*/
   }
}
```

As you can see, the method body is pretty useless, because I'm trying to figure out why it won't accept my calls, so I made sure the problem wasn't in the body.

I'm using Postman to call it.

[image]
[image]

And I get this result (The wording may slightly differ from the standard, since for some reason mine is in French (probably Windows' fault somehow), and I've roughly translated the important parts):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17 - Rapport d''erreur</title>
        <style type="text/css">h1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} h2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} h3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} b {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} p {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;} a {color:black;} a.name {color:black;} .line {height:1px;background-color:#525D76;border:none;}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Etat HTTP 415 - Unsupported Media Type</h1>
        <div class="line"></div>
        <p>
            <b>type</b> Status Report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>message</b>
            <u>Unsupported Media Type</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>description</b>
            <u>The server has denied this request because the request entity is in a format that is not supported by the queried resource with the specified method.</u>
        </p>
        <hr class="line">
        <h3>Apache Tomcat/9.0.0.M17</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here are the two important classes:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class LoginBean {
    @XmlElement public String email;
    @XmlElement public String password;
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "user") 

public class User implements Serializable {  

    public enum accountType {
        Admin,
        User
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
    private int _id; 
    private String _firstName; 
    private String _lastName; 
    private String _email; 
    private String _password; 
    private Date _registerDate; 
    private Date _lastOnlineDate; 
    private Time _lastOnlineTime; 
    private String _lastOnlineIP;
    private accountType _type;  
    private String _country;  
    private String _province;

    public User(int id){  
        this._id = id;
    }  

    public User() {
        this._id = -1;
    }

    public int getId() { 
        return _id; 
    }  

    @XmlElement 
    public void setId(int id) {
        this._id = id; 
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return _firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this._firstName = firstName;
    }

     (lots of skipped content here)

    public boolean isValid() {
        if (isNullOrWhitespace(_email))
            return false;   
        if (isNullOrWhitespace(_password))
            return false;   
        if (_id < 1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: change the url to http://localhost:8080/login

Comment: @AnitaYip This gives me a 404, as would be expected. My web.xml is correctly mapped, because I can access the GET method by just changing login to users. I'll edit the question to add a bit more of the mapping

Comment: suppose you need to change the `POST` method to accept `@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)` hope this [post](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/) may be helpful.

Comment: Does the `getUsers` endpoint work? I'm not sure what implementation of ws-rs you're using, or if you might need to register an additional component in order to get free JSON serialization.

Comment: Yes it works fine

Comment: I just see that you have @Path("/UserService")  at the class level? Did you try localhost:8080/UserService/login url? Are you getting 404 for this too?

Comment: Yes, I also have the "rest" part in the web.xml and the project was created using the wizard that setup the "RoomManagement" part right. As mentioned in another comment, the path is probably fine since sending a GET to /users works fine.